# "Rather than doing" vs. "rather than do"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, present-participles, bare-infinitive

> - I can't do anything rather than waiting.
> - I can't do anything rather than wait.

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: "other than wait".

Comment: The verb after "rather" should follow the same form of the other verb. The verb after "rather" is "wait". And the other verb of the sentence is "do", so it will be "wait", not "waiting". If it were "doing", after "rather" it would have been "waiting".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idiomatically (and logically, it seems to me) *neither* of OP's suggestions are valid. It should be...

> *I can't do anything **other than** wait* (or ***but/except*** wait)

Valid constructions using *rather* include, for example,...

> *I **would/will** do anything rather than wait.*
>   *?I'll do anything rather than waiting*.

I've marked the second one there with *?* because it doesn't sound very good to me, but I'm pretty sure at least some native speakers will find it perfectly acceptable. People have different ideas about where (the increasingly common) use of gerunds is "reasonable".

Comment: Does this also apply here (from a printed book): Rather than attempt (should that be _attempting_?) a comprehensive treatment of these options, we’ll just use some of them in our examples.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade: Well, like I said, different people will have different opinions in this area. In your *exact* context I can't see anyone objecting to the continuous / gerund ***attempting*** rather than infinitive ***attempt***. But as the question mark in my example in the above answer implies, most people would *always* use *...rather than **wait*** there - and at least *some* of them would probably say that ***waiting*** was in fact "wrong". I may be mistaken, but I think if you always use the infinitive, no-one would ever say that was actually incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is acceptable, at least in U.S. usage.  Ordinarily, *other than* or *but* and not *rather than* is used in sentences like these.  Also, I'd prefer “can do nothing other than” or “can do nothing but”  to “can't do anything other than”.

After those substitutions, the phrasing with *wait* is closer to grammatical correctness.  Consider the following conversation, and imagine it with *waiting* rather than *wait*.

> A: What will you do?
>   B: I will wait because I can do nothing but wait.